# jQuery: Selecting Elements by Class Returning jQuery.fn.init(9) - Cannot Read .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to obtain all elements with a certain class name using the following code:

```
productPrices = $('.product-price');
```

However this is returning:

> jQuery.fn.init(9) [div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, div.product-price, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]

I believe this is why I cannot access the value of each index; when I try to execute this code:

```
    // Clone original prices
for(var i = 0; i < productPrices.length; i++) {
    productPrices[i].val().replace("£", "");
    console.log(productPrices[i].textContent);
    britishPrices[i] = productPrices[i].textContent;
}
```

I get the following error:

> productPrices[i].val is not a function

As I said, I believe this is being caused by a strange return value when selecting the class values. I have also tried using .text() as well as .html() too.

If anyone could aid my understanding on this I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
productPrices[i]
```

should be

```
productPrices.eq(i)
```

Bracket notation on a jQuery object breaks the DOM Element out of the result stack and it is no longer a jQuery object, which `val()` is a method of.  To keep it as a jQuery object, use `eq(#)` instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Now I am getting the error 'Cannot set property '0' of undefined' for the line `britishPrices[i] = productPrices.eq(i).val();`.

Comment: So your britishPrices array is undefined, :)

Comment: you are right, I had not initialized britishPrices array correctly. Thank you for your help.